# Chrome is reporting about "Unexpected token" when running a AJAX request

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I'm trying to run the following AJAX request for sending data and CSRF data to Codeigniter, but Chrome Developer Tool is reporting about a "Unexpected token". 
I haven't been able to fix this issue, however I am thinking the "data" field is causing the error.

**This is my AJAX request call:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#country').on('change',function(){
        var countryID = $(this).val();
        if(countryID){
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'/index.php/campaigns/fetch_departments',
                data:{'csrf_token':'4932809e3753b95b81245ff4439a121d','country_id:'+countryID},
                success:function(html){
                    $('#state').html(html);
                    $('#city').html('<option value="">Select state first</option>'); 
                }
            }); 
        }else{
            $('#state').html('<option value="">Select country first</option>');
            $('#city').html('<option value="">Select state first</option>'); 
        }
    });
    ...
```

Comment: `'country_id='+countryID` should be `'country_id': countryID`

Comment: Please show the actual generated Javascript that appears in the page the browser receives so we can see what your PHP is generating for the actual script.  You can get this with View/Source in the browser.  This will also help you see what the actual generated script looks like and make it more likely you can spot your own coding error.

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
'country_id:'+countryID
```

To:

```
'country_id': countryID
```

As it stands, you're declaring a data item called 'country_id:xxxxx' with no value.